# how to set “android:scrollbarSize” ？

Tags: android

I set `android:scrollbarSize ='20dip'` for `TextView in Android`, but it's invalid. I don't know what happened. Here is my code:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:scrollbarSize="10px"
```

Comment: Possibly exact duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736768/android-scrollview-scrollbarsize

Answer (score 1):

Use this, `<item name="scrollbarSize">10dip</item>`. A
lso refer this link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14317